How can i compare two time series in order to detect directionality preference?
Let’s say I am looking at two assets which are correlated, for example a=S&P500 and b=10-year US Treasury Yields (inversed).
I want to detect when the strength of the change is different.
For example,
When b move up by 1x, a move up by 2x.
When b move down by 1x, a move down by 0.5x or even flat or up.
What’s the best way to capture this?

If you think the response is not symmetric you could, for example, do a regression with $\Delta a$ as the dependent and two independent variables $Max(0,\Delta b)$ and $Min(0,\Delta b)$. In other words you are looking at positive and negative changes in b separately. Compare the coefficients of the two variables to see if they are equal.

I think constructing and studying the results of a vector autoregression might help you understand the direction of "causality" (if such exists). Incorporating the terms suggested by @nbbo2 in comment above into that VAR is a possibility.

I would probably use a rolling window for historical beta (probably with the less volatile asset as the reference; or the market, as it is usually known) that updates itself with the most recent observations (in this case, log returns).
Personally, I prefer to use the past 21 days of log returns to compute historical beta as it is not too long (short) to be barely (overly) affected by the incorporation of the most recent observation.
If we go by your example, the beta ($a$, S&P 500 to $b$, US T yields, where US T yields is the "market") would originally be $+2$ (or somewhere around that if we assume the history perfectly gives us this value). However, incorporating the most recent observation, say when $b$ moves down by 1x, and instead of $a$ moving down by 2; it goes down by 0.5x, stays flat or moves up - this would mean that the most recent observation offsets/lowers the original historical (rolling window) beta to a lower value. That would mean that the newest observation would lower the beta to below $+2$.

Rolling Beta (Dynamic Correlation)
Beta measures the sensitivity of an asset's returns relative to a benchmark. In your case, the S&P 500 (a) would be the asset, and the inverse 10-year US Treasury yield (b) could act as the benchmark.
This will give you insight into how the relationship between the two assets changes over time, capturing periods where the S&P 500 moves with a greater or lesser magnitude compared to the yield.
